# Making a costly Python array global

Tags: python, global-variables

I want to avoid recomputing a costly array in Python. Luckily it is immutable - so "copying a pointer" would suffice. Unluckily the program is divided into a load of modules, and I need it here and there and variables are at most module-global in Python. How do I "import" the array into another module after I have computed it once (e.g. in main)?

- One single program: My project colleagues will shoot me :-)
- "Piping through" as parameter via the function calls: I shoot myself. :-) (Also, think of the dependencies...)
- Put all functions that need it into the same module: Egad, the architecture is ruined. Also, I don't have the parameters for the array computation at that location.

(sorry, don't have any useful code)

Well, the actual result is that the program is a snail and making 1000000 runs to get meaningful statistics is out of question...

Comment: How big is this array? why not save it as a csv or even a pickle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the bigArray computation in module bigArray.py, you should be able to use it in any other module by importing it specifically:

```
from bigArray import bigArray
```

If you want the array to be computed only when it is first referenced, your bigArray.py module can expose it using a function.

```
# bigArray.py
#
bigArray = None
def getBigArray():
    if bigArray is None:
       ... build the bigArray ...
    return bigArray

# otherModule.py
#
from bigArray import getBigArray

   ...
   arr = getBigArray()  # to use the array
   ...
```

Comment: Sounds legit! I will time the programs and post the result here...as soon as the program is ready. For the record, ~1000000 elements are not *that* big, but with a lot of nested calls, it adds.

Comment: I fiddled a bit with the construction because I also had to consider the annoying feature of Python that it has no global-global variables (only module-global). Before: 2 min - After: 4 sec - Have a well-earned checkmark :-)

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct (feel free to correct me otherwise), then if something is a global variable in say `workspace.py` and I have another program `project.py` I can run `from workspace import *` to get the same global variable namespace as my `workspace.py` file. This is generally frowned upon though because you may unwittingly reuse the same variable name without realizing it, thus breaking your program. It also (needlessly in most cases) loads **all** the variables into RAM essentially making `project.py` just an extension of your original `workspace.py` with access to the same classes, methods, and variables.